# Garage door immediately reversing when trying to close

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a Ryobi garage door opener. It's been working fine until recently when trying to close it. The opener will try to close when pressing the button but then immediately reverse back open. I don't believe the safety sensor is obstructed; when waving my hand through the sensor I can see the green LED turning off and on indicating it's getting blocked and unblocked. The safety sensor LED is normally on when not being obstructed, and it is on when trying to close the opener.

I've tried disconnecting the trolley from the opener bullet. While the trolley is disconnected:

- With the door in the closed position, the opener bullet will close fully.
- With the door in any open position, the opener bullet will immediately reverse back to open in the same manner as when the trolley is attached.

What else can I check?

Comment: does it close if you hold the button?

Comment: Does the door immediately reverse when you press a button to make it go down? It sounds like the clutch is set too loose. There is an adjustment procedure for the clutch, but it does interact with the limit setting and it does take some time and patience to get the settings right. You could just tighten the clutch in increments (while keeping track of the changes) and see if this has an effect.

Answer (score 2):

Does the door move freely?  If the sensor isn't obstructed, the other cause for reversal would typically be down force.   If it takes too much force to close the door, it may think it's obstructed by something that's not blocking the sensor, and will reverse.   The amount of force required to reverse is adjustable, but you shouldn't adjust it without understanding why it changed, as it is a safety issue if not adjusted properly (think crushing a pet or toddler).    Please consult the instructions for your unit for proper adjustment.

Comment: One common cause of excessive downforce is a drive screw that needs lubrication.

Answer (score 2):

My door started reversing near the bottom, and, without thinking it through, I went through the adjustment procedure in the manual. Twice. The door still reversed about 8 inches from down all the way.

Then a realization: the door was not hitting the floor and reversing, but reversing as it *approached* the floor!

With the door stopped off the floor, I swept off the bottom of the door with a broom, and problem solved. There were cobwebs on the bottom of the door holding leaves and dust which went into the path of the light beam as the door approached the floor.